# How to know asynchronously detect if async subprocess has terminated

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` to launch a long-running process (a daemon sort of).

However I cannot await on it to know if the process has succeeded/failed. I have to asynchronously detect if the process has failed and handle it at that point. Otherwise I leave the subprocess daemon running and communicate with it over TCP/IP.

I could use a signal handler on SIGCHLD, but does asyncio have some built-in functionality to create a handler for the subprocess?

```
import asyncio
import subprocess

async def main():
    command = ["./some-long-running-daemon"]
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(process.returncode) # this is None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I discovered that async create subprocess doesn't seem to behave well with the `SIGCHILD` at all (the handler doesn't even run). Whereas `subprocess.Popen` does. The `Popen` also has a `poll()` method whereas the async subprocess doesn't. It seems `Popen` is the right thing to use.

Comment: Since you are using pipes, you will have to do something like `await process.communicate(b'some input')`. If you don't you might deadlock your subprocess. But once that returns you know the process is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're happy to write a signal handler, why not just create a new task that waits on the process to finish? You can then have your main task continue on doing whatever it wants.

```
import asyncio
import subprocess

async def child_done(proc):
    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    print('child done. output:', stdout, '-- return code was:', proc.returncode)

async def main():
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    asyncio.create_task(child_done(proc))
    # do other stuff
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('main done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Which gives you output like:

```
child done. output: b'asyncio-test.py\n' -- return code was: 0
main done
```